# To do searching in an array with some keyword

Tags: c#, arrays, string, c#-4.0

I have an array which is like

```
books={'java 350','Photoshop 225','php 210','JavaScript 80','python 180','jquery 250'}
```

my input for search as be like `"ph2"` it retrieve both `Photoshop 225`,`php 210` in drop-down menu what is the exact string function to do this task or any set codes available to do this task.

I'm using some build in function like

```
if (array.Any(keyword.Contains))
```

and

```
if (array.Contains(keyword))
```

it's doesn't help what exactly i want any one pls help me to solve this thanks in advance.....

Comment: Can you share the code which performs search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More flexible approach:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic; // add reference
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            string[] books = { "java 350", "Photoshop 225", "php 210", "JavaScript 80", "python 180", "jquery 250" };

            string input = "*" + string.Join ("*", "ph2".ToArray ()) + "*"; // will be *p*h*2*

            var matches = books.Where (x => LikeOperator.LikeString (x, input, CompareMethod.Text));
        }
    }
}
```